# Flex - drop down list stuck down if it opens alert dialog

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

I need to show a warning dialog after the users picks a certain choice in a drop down list.

It is a simple drop down list in flex (flash builder 4.6), that opens an alert dialog.   When I do this, the drop down list is 'stuck' down, meaning after the choice is selected, normally the drop down list closes back up, but when I display an alert, it stays open and you have to click a choice again to close it.

drop down list mxml:

```
       <s:DropDownList id="typeEventDropDownList"
                        change="typeEventDropDownList_changeHandler(event)"
                        selectedIndex="0">
            <s:layout>
                <s:VerticalLayout requestedRowCount="10"/>
            </s:layout>
            <s:dataProvider>
                <s:ArrayList source="[ChooseAction,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i]" />
            </s:dataProvider>
        </s:DropDownList>
```

drop down list handler:

```
protected function typeEventDropDownList_changeHandler(event:IndexChangeEvent):void
            {
                     // if this alert is called, the drop down list 'sticks' open.   if the alert is removed, it closes normally
            Alert.show("bla bla bla", "Warning",mx.controls.Alert.OK , this, null);  // does not matter if a method is called from here
                        }
```

I have already tried a few combinations of using the closeDropDown (and even calling OpenDropDown) before and after the alert dialog, which seems to make no difference:

```
         typeEventDropDownList.openDropDown();  //have tried opening and closing, closing only, before and after alert - no difference
         typeEventDropDownList.closeDropDown(true);  // have tried true and false  no difference
```

Comment: Does the 'this' in your Alert box control refer to the DropDownList?  Or some parent of the DropDownList?

Comment: I would think if you listened for the `close` event instead of the `change` event, the dropdown would be closed _before_ the Alert was displayed. Of course, if you really need to know whether the `selectedIndex` has actually changed, you might have to determine this yourself.

Comment: The drop down appears in a Group, which is inside a TitleWindow.  So I believe 'this' is the TitleWindow.

Comment: RIAStar, your solution worked.    All I had to do was change the drop down from 'change' to 'close', then change my event type to DropDownEvent and it worked, drop down closes, and all the rest of the code worked fine as-is.  Thanks!

Comment: @ScottSzretter:  How does the rest work "as is"?  I thought you said it should only display the Alert warning for a certain choice in the DDL?  Wouldn't the `close` event trigger the warning for ***every*** choice?  I'm running into this same issue, but my Alert gives a YES/NO choice.  But if they choose NO, then it should keep whatever was selected.  If I use `close`, it seems too late at that point to go back.

Comment: sorry, did not include that code.  there are a few ways to do it, but I usually do something like this to identify a specific drop down choice : if(event.target.selectedItem == "Eval")

Answer (score 1):

**You can have something like**

```
protected function typeEventDropDownList_changeHandler(event:IndexChangeEvent):void
{
callLater(DisplayAlert); 
}

protected function DisplayAlert()
{
//Display your alert here , i.e., Alert.show()
}
```

**It worked for me.**

Answer (score 0):

Where are you putting the close list code? This should work:

```
protected function typeEventDropDownList_changeHandler(event:IndexChangeEvent):void
{
    typeEventDropDownList.closeDropDown(true);
    Alert.show("bla bla bla", "Warning",mx.controls.Alert.OK , this, null);
}
```